# Haxe: openfl test works but not lime build

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe, openfl, haxelib, lime-haxe

I'm in the process of moving all my projects to individual modules in IntelliJ rather than having one module in the entire git repo, and my IntelliJ builds stopped working. I notice it uses lime builds even though my module is set to openfl (and always has as far as I know)

```
openfl test flash -debug
```

this works

```
lime build GassyRickAstley.xml flash -debug -verbose
```

this does not. [Full gist of both -v](https://gist.github.com/Geokureli/770e2cc748590b243157c31e5979e555)

```
Lime Command-Line Tools (2.9.1)

Initializing project...
Using project file: GassyRickAstley.xml
Warning: Could not read HXCPP config: /Users/booboo/.hxcpp_config.xml
Using target platform: FLASH

Running command: UPDATE
 - Embedding asset: removed for brevity
 - Copying template file: removed for brevity

Running command: BUILD
 - Running command: haxe -main ApplicationMain -cp /usr/local/lib/haxe/lib/flixel/git -D flixel=4.3.0 -cp /usr/local/lib/haxe/lib/openfl/3,6,1 -D openfl=3.6.1 -cp /usr/local/lib/haxe/lib/lime/2,9,1 -D lime=2.9.1 -cp /usr/local/lib/haxe/lib/actuate/1,8,7 -D actuate=1.8.7 -cp /usr/local/lib/haxe/lib/ash/1,5,4/src -D ash=1.5.4 -cp source -cp lib -cp /usr/local/lib/haxe/lib/openfl/3,6,1/extern -cp ../Krakel/source -cp ../../lib/HxAssert/src -D native-trace -D HXCPP_QUIET -D openfl-next -D tools=2.9.1 -D flash-use-stage -D no-compilation -D openfl-flash -D verbose=1 -D web --macro flixel.system.macros.FlxDefines.run() -swf-lib export/flash/obj/assets.swf -swf-version 11.8 -swf export/flash/bin/GassyRickAstley.swf -cp export/flash/haxe -debug

georges-mbp:Gassy Rick Astley booboo$
```

It doesn't seem like anything went wrong, but I'm pretty shit with analyzing terminal output.

For now I can just build manually, but not having breakpoints is gonna get pretty lame, pretty fast. Any help is appreciated.

**Bonus question**. When I run/test the project in open fl and close the game's window the active terminal process never ends. I have to close the terminal, reopen and cd my directory again. is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it may have worked. `openfl test flash` is similar to running `openfl build flash && openfl run flash`, which in turn should behave practically the same as `lime build flash && lime run flash`.

I think your `lime build flash` command is working properly, but is exiting because the application has finished building. If you use `lime test flash` instead, it might build-and-run for you, as the other command does?

Comment: So that's definitely the case and I feel dumb. I did lime build because I was trying to mimic intelliJ's actions to find out why it wasn't building.